# Reusing the form value object when editing in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a template-driven form like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
  <input type="text" name="name" [ngModel]="person.name">
  <input type="text" name="ssn"  [ngModel]="person.ssn">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to use it both for creating and editing person records. If I enter some values and click the submit button `f.value` is something like this:

```
{ name: 'John', ssn: '1234567' }
```

It works as it is, but I'd like like my form template to be less verbose. I want to avoid binding each input to the corresponding property of the form value object when editing. Is it possible to bind the whole object to the form value?

I hopped to be able to bind the object prevously retrieved from `f.value` to the form, but couldn't.

I'd guess this should work, but it doesn't:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(f.value)" [ngModel]="person">
  <input type="text" name="name" ngModel>
  <input type="text" name="ssn" ngModel>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This also doesn't work:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(f.value)" [value]="person">
  <input type="text" name="name" ngModel>
  <input type="text" name="ssn" ngModel>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What's the best way to acheive bravity and elegant form templates?

Comment: To achieve this you should use [reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms) instead of template driven forms.

Comment: @cyrix is Reactive-Forms have in-built functionality ? default one lostfocus?